# Core function of Prism (.NET)

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, prism

What are the core functions of Prism(.NET) Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Basically Prism provides you with guidance in the form of examples, documentation and reusable components to build applications in a modularized way, following design patterns (such as MVVM), which should enable you to have more maintainable and testable code.

So this might sound a little bit abstract; perhaps after reading some chapters in the documentation and checking the QuickStarts you will have a clearer perspective.

All in all, if you're planning to use WPF/Silverlight, and you're interested in developing high quality code using proven patterns without reinventing the wheel, then Prism might be a good choice for you :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all Prism is not for the small applications, it is a framework which helps in managing WPF or Silverlight applications in a loosely coupled way. By using Prism we can have views of Modules, in the shell which contanis regions.
So by incorporating Prism we can have a better managing abilities for our application, this allows the independent code development, testing, modules expandibility, seperation of dependency from modules onto the seperate central class via dependency injectors etc.
You can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141(v=PandP.40).aspx